# Array list variables printing

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a problem with **ArrayList** variables printing out to output. What am I doing wrong?

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            al.add(new Calc(i, tan.ro, tan.stro));
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            Object ol = al.get(i);
            Calc temp = (Calc) ol;
            System.out.println("Calculations = "+ temp.getMass());
            System.out.println(al.get(i));
```

My output:

```
Calculation = 5.0
App.Calc@15db9742
Calculation = 40.0
App.Calc@6d06d69c
```

I want to change that App.Calc@6d06d69c to correct value of `i`

Comment: You need to override the `toString` method in class `Calc`.

Comment: as a sidenote, make use of the generics for you `ArrayList al`.

Comment: @Jasper But if my `i` is int variable?

Comment: It hasn’t got anything to do with `i`. @Jesper is correct. Please read the explanation in the link: [How do I print my Java object without getting “SomeType@2f92e0f4”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4). Thx.

Comment: Guys, Thank you very much :) Its working!